# How do I assign variable names to every variables in my tuple?

Tags: python

I am trying to assign a name to every variable in a tuple. So my tuple is:

```
grid_defs = ((-0.073, 0.073, 4e-4), (-0.071, 0.075, 4e-4), (-0.065, 0.004, 4e-4))
```

and I want to give every number a variable name like this:

```
grid_defs = ((gx0, gx1, gxs), (gy0, gy1, gys), (gz0, gz1, gzs))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: use a dictionary

Comment: This looks like good case to use namedtuples.

Answer (score 2):

You just have the assignment backwards. You want to unpack the value of `grid_defs` into a tuple-like target.

```
((gx0, gx1, gxs), (gy0, gy1, gys), (gz0, gz1, gzs)) = grid_defs
```

Answer (score 1):

You should [look at namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).  This data structure will allow you to create tuples and refer to their values by name, which may be what you want.  You may also want to consider using a dictionary instead of a tuple depending on your specific use case.

If what you actually want is to unpack an existing tuple then you should see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70948052/17244117).

Comment: thank you I will look into namedtuples and dictionary